# Validate optional XML element in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

How would I validate `RequiresPaidSubscription` only when provided?

```
<xs:element name="RequiresPaidSubscription" minOccurs="0" >
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="True|true|False|false|0|1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

The `minOccurs="0"` doesn't seem to do anything for me with the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minOccurs="0"` occurrence constraint indicates optionality in the context of a parent element, which you've not shown.  For example:

```
<xs:element name="Magazine">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="RequiresPaidSubscription" minOccurs="0" >
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="True|true|False|false|0|1"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Here, `RequiresPaidSubscription` would be an optional child element of `Magazine`.